Simple shell commands never finish, but only on external drive
Most of the time, my Mac's Terminal works great. However, when I use it to navigate the file system of my WD My Passport 1TB external drive, it... almost works. Almost. Simple commands like cd and ls work normally except that they don't appear to finish -- they leave the Terminal waiting at the last line of the ls results, rather than presenting the prompt. Effectively, I have to ^C after every single command (and I better hope it was actually finished when I do that).

This is a 2020 Intel Macbook Pro, 13" display, running Sonoma 14.4.1. The shell is zsh.
I haven't tried waiting more than a minute or so, on the assumption that it really shouldn't take that long for an ls.
It's only the WD 1TB drive that does it. Browsing files works normally* on my little SanDisk thumb drive and the Seagate external drive that I use for Time Machine. (* The Time Machine drive won't run ls, but that appears to be a Time Machine thing, and the "operation not permitted" error shows up promptly before going back to the normal prompt.)
Some commands work normally -- tar -xzvf on a 53GB tarball just finished and exited to the prompt. man tar did not, nor did less or a simple sed.

Why is this happening? Why is it only the one drive that does it?
edit: More information as requested in comments.

The problem drive is formatted ExFAT. The thumb drive is FAT32, the Time Machine drive is Mac OS Extended (Journaled), and the laptop's built-in SSD is APFS.
The problem disappears when I use a simple prompt (PS1="$ "). The problem prompt is "(base) [%T] %n @ %1~$(git_prompt_info) »", where git_prompt_info is a function defined in ~/.oh-my-zsh/lib/git.zsh :

# Outputs current branch info in prompt format
function git_prompt_info() {
  local ref
  if [[ "$(command git config --get oh-my-zsh.hide-status 2>/dev/null)" != "1" ]]; then
    ref=$(command git symbolic-ref HEAD 2> /dev/null) || \
    ref=$(command git rev-parse --short HEAD 2> /dev/null) || return 0
    echo "$ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_PREFIX${ref#refs/heads/}$(parse_git_dirty)$ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_SUFFIX"
  fi
}

Any idea why that might cause problems only on the one drive -- or, failing that, a way to use a different prompt only when that function hangs up? (I do like having the branch in my prompt and would love to give that function some way to handle whatever error is happening here.)

What filesystem is on the problematic drive?

It sounds like your shell prompt is trying to use something from the current directory, like display the pathname. But that wouldn't explain why it's dependent on the command.

Does it happen if you set a very simple prompt, like PS1='$ '?

@MarcWilson -- The problem drive is ExFAT. In case it's relevant: the thumb drive is FAT32, the Time Machine drive is Mac OS Extended (Journaled), and the laptop's built-in SSD is APFS.

@Barmar -- aha, it does not! My previous PS1 was (base) [%T] %n @ %1~$(git_prompt_info) », where git_prompt_info is a function from zsh that specifies git branch and such. Changing the prompt to $  fixed the problem, as did changing it back to the old one and just dropping the git_prompt_info function. I'll edit the function into the question text; any chance you can see why it was causing trouble?

git_prompt_info seems to be part of oh-my-zsh, which I'm not very familiar with. I don't know why it would have problems only after certain commands.

@Barmar well thank you so much regardless! Wish I could upvote comments, haha.

So if you go to that directory and just issue the function at a prompt, it hangs up?   That's just up to three invocations of git, shouldn't be difficult to figure out which one is hanging it up.  a ps should show which command it is.

Is access via Finder also slow? BTW, I'm using a 2 TB WD, formatted as ExFAT, and it works like a charm.

@user1934428, belatedly, no -- access via Finder works normally.

In this case, I would separately time the functions invoke inside your prompt, i.e. command git ..... Is one of them particularily slow?
